# How to change the MySQL root password?

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans, change-password

I'm facing some issue when installation in MySQL-Server. I tried to change the root password several times but it does not work as I expected. Finally when I'm going to change the password It's shows like this kind of output. How can I resolve this problem. When I going to connect to the sql database using netbeans it's output shows this error.

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost')
```

mysql >  `select user, authentication_string plugin from mysql.user;`

[image]

Comment: *I tried to change the root password several times but it does not work as I expected.* How do you do this (precisely)? What output or error message was returned (completely)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have correct password, but NetBeans cannot connect to TCP port 3306 at all. As soon as JDBC driver cannot connect to unix socket, please try to bind MySQL Server to tcp port 3306.

I think that it will be enough to check your MySQL configuration and find "skip-networking" option and remove it.

Please check /etc/my.cnf.d directory and /etc/my.cnf file for this line, delete it and restart MySQL server.

If you need to change the root password, the easiest way is to run mysql_secure_installation script from root user.